# How to iterate "any" object array in Type script and access its property

Tags: typescript

I have this JSON data object:

```
    var dataObjects = [
         {
          "Name": "Date & Time",
          "Type": "Date",
          "Value": "2019-12-11"
          },
          {
          "Name": "Activity",
          "Type": "String",
          "Value": "ADD"
          }
      ]
```

I want to build a new JSON data array object out of this one except the new one has the date formatted from "2019-12-11" to "December 11, 2019".

Here is my attempt after googling around but I'm getting a lot of syntax error.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge in Typescript and Javascript, that's why I ask for help because something simple to you still gives me a lot of difficulties.

```js
        public FunctionA(dataObjects: any[]): object 
        {
           let returnObj: any = {}
           let returnObjArray: any = [];

           for(let obj in dataObjects){

             var dateValue = obj.Date;

             if(obj.Type == "Date"){
               dateValue = obj.Date.Format()
             }
             returnObj = {"Name", obj.Name, "Type": obj.Type, "Value": dateValue };
             returnObjArray.push(returnObj);
           }

           return returnObjArray;
        }
```

I sort of understand my error is that I somehow has to specify what is this "any" array before I can use its property.  However, I tried declare it below and I still have error:

```
    dataObjects: Array[{ Name: string, Type: string, Value: string }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can achieve your goal:

```
 var dataObjects = [
    {
    "Name": "Date & Time",
    "Type": "Date",
    "Value": "2019-12-11"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Activity",
    "Type": "String",
    "Value": "ADD"
    }
]
type dataType = {Name: string, Type: string, Value: string};

function A(dataObjects: dataType[]): dataType[] 
{
    let returnObjArray: dataType[] = [];

    dataObjects.forEach((obj:dataType)  => {
        if(obj.Type === "Date"){
        obj.Value = moment(obj.Value).toString("MMM dd, yyyy");
        }
        returnObjArray.push(obj);
    });
    return returnObjArray;
}
```

`moment(obj.Value).toString("MMM dd, yyyy");` is where you can convert your old date string to your desired format (using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) package).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is this:

```
Array<{ Name: string, Type: string, Value: string }>
```

or this:

```
{ Name: string, Type: string, Value: string }[]
```

But even better is to give it a name:

```
type MyObject = {
 Name: string,
 Type: string,
 Value: string 
}
```

And then use `MyObject[]` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it is to create your own `DataObject` interface and use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create your new array.

```js
interface DataObject {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  value: string;
}

var dataObjects: DataObject[] = [
  {
   "name": "Date & Time",
   "type": "Date",
   "value": "2019-12-11"
   },
   {
   "name": "Activity",
   "type": "String",
   "value": "ADD"
   }
]

function convertDate(date: string): string {
  // Your conversion code here.
  return date;
}

function convertDataObjects(dataObjects: DataObject[]): DataObject[] {
  return dataObjects.map(obj => {
    return {name: obj.name, type: obj.type, value: convertDate(obj.value)};
  });
}

console.log(convertDataObjects(dataObjects));
```